# Present perfect continuous vs. Passive

Tags: present-progressive

"have been locked in the bathroom for hours".  So i have a couple of questions. First  Is it present perfect continuous or present perfect?  Second if it is present perfect then why perfect continuous has not been used? and last can it also be used as passive  e.g. I have been locked (by someone) so I want to know if both can be used? Though I have already asked this question but could not get any satisfactory answer.

Comment: You've already asked this question. Why was the answer(s) unsatisfactory?

Answer (score 0):

This is present perfect. We don't use present perfect continuous here because your emphasis is on the result. The continuous focuses on the action.
Do you know the story of Goldilocks and the Three Bears?
Papa and Mama bear always ask, "Who has been eating my porridge?"
That's because Goldilocks didn't like their porridge and it's not finished. The action can been seen as still going on.
Baby bear asks, "who has eaten my porridge?"
That is because Goldilocks liked his porridge and ate it all. The result is an empty bowl.
You've been locked in the bathroom for hours. The result is you can't move. When you're freed, your rescuer might ask, "How long have you been locked in here?" The rescuer is questioning the action.